# authjs authentication and protected routing with external JWT

Tags: next.js, jwt, next.js13, next-auth

I have a server RESTful service and for authentication I'm using magic link approach.

Following request to the service sends an email to the destination with the login link.

```http
POST /auth/magic_login
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "destination": "user@gmail.com"
}
```

Link look as follows

```
http://restserver/auth/magic_login/callback?token=sometoken
```

When the user clicks on the link, access token will be returned back. With the token in the request as a Bearer token, protected resources in the service can be accessed.

```json
{
    "token": "somejwtaccesstoken"
}
```

Now, I want to have a NextJS 14 application as the client frontend. I would like to have following features.

- I want to do SSR based on the RESTful service resources
- I want to do CSR based on the RESTful service resources
- I want to do protected & authorized routes based on the user role according to the token
- I don't want to handle the user session that requires storing data in a database

So, in summary,

- In the NextJs server, I should have the access to the JWT token to do SSR & protected & authenticated routing (JWT contains the user roles).
- In the client (browser), I should have the access to the JWT to make direct requests to RESTful service.

This is the first time I'm using NextJs and I have no idea how to do this using NextJs and AuthJs.

I don't know if this is how it should be done but as an initiation, my first attempt was to use a form to submit the token. I used AuthJs credentials provider and do the authentication through that assuming eventually `authorize` would send `restserver/auth/magic_login/callback` within it.

#### package.json

```json
//package.json
"next": "14.1.2",
"next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.15",
```

#### @/auth.ts

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut
} = NextAuth({
  providers: [Credentials({
    name: 'Auth using magic link',
    credentials: {
      username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
      token: { label: "Token", type: "text" }
    },
    async authorize(credentials, req) {
      console.log('cred: ', credentials)
      const user = { id: "1", name: "srinesha", email: "srinesha@orli.tech" }

      if (user) {
        return user
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  })],
  session: { strategy: 'jwt' }
})
```

#### @/action/login.ts

```js
'use server'

import { signIn } from "@/auth";

export const loginIn = (values: { token: string }) => {
  try {
    signIn("credentials", {
      token: values.token,
      redirectTo: '/settings'
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

#### @/app/auth/login.tsx

```js
'use client'

import { loginIn } from "@/actions/login"
import { FormEvent } from "react"

const LoginPage = () => {

  const onSubmit = (ev: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    ev.preventDefault()

    loginIn({
      token: 'callback_token'
    })
  }

  return <div>
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
}

export default LoginPage
```

```js
import { auth } from "./auth"
import { defaultLoginRedirect, apiAuthPrefix, authRoutes, publicRoutes } from "./routes"

export default auth((req) => {
  const { nextUrl } = req;
  console.log('auth details for ' + req.url, req.auth)
})

// Optionally, don't invoke Middleware on some paths
export const config = {
  // matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
  matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
}
```

However when click on the login button I get following error in the NextJs server console thouse I can see the `authorize` function get the information successfully, and returns the user. On the browser I can see `authjs.callback-url` & `authjs.csrf-token` cookies being set by the response.

```
cred:  { token: 'callback_token', callbackUrl: '/settings' }
Error: NEXT_REDIRECT
    at getRedirectError (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/client/compon
ents/redirect.js:49:19)
    at redirect (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/red
irect.js:60:11)
    at signIn (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@5.0.0-beta.15_next@14.1.2_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/lib/actions.js:5
4:73) {
  digest: 'NEXT_REDIRECT;replace;http://localhost:3000/settings;303;',
  mutableCookies: p {
    _parsed: Map(2) {
      'authjs.callback-url' => [Object],
      'authjs.session-token' => [Object]
    },
    _headers: HeadersList {
      cookies: [Array],
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    }
  }
}
```

If I navigate to a different route, though cookies are set, `auth` is null.

output from the middleware

```
//  console.log('auth details for ' + req.url, req.auth)
auth details for http://localhost:3000/ null
```

Is this not the approach I'm support to be doing? If I'm on the correct path, what have I done wrong here? Why `req.auth` is null?